# Can i plug an 12v DC to a 9v Pedal?

Tags: guitar, effects-pedal

pretty much as the title goes..
is it okay to plug an 12v DC power supply(Voodoo Lab) to 9v pedal(ADA GCS-5)?

---

*Power Supply* >> [Voodoo Lab ISO-5's Manual for reference](http://www.voodoolab.com/manuals/pedal_power_iso-5_manual.pdf)
*Pedal* >> [ADA GCS-5's Manual for reference](http://www.adaamps.com/Media/GCS-5%20USER%20MANUAL%2070141x%20v.0.1%20a.pdf)

more info regarding the Pedal and Power Supply

- my Power Supply got 6 power output

  - 3x[all available] 9v 100mA
  - 9v[used by a Pedal which couldn't run below 150mA]/12v[available] 400mA
  - 18v[Used] 100mA)
- ADA GCS-5's manual did say that "*The GCS-5
  is an all-analog circuit that runs on a standard 9-volt AC adapter (ADA Part Number 240013G5) **or a pedal board power supply rated at 200mA or more**.*". Which is quite ambiguous whether if its okay to put an unregulated 12v DC on it.

Comment: I don't know any of this equipment but I would not suggest using a supply with too high a voltage, especially not an unregulated one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

15% above seems to be recognised as safe, but here it's twice that. I've done it in desperate circumstances (borrowed psu in middle of gig), and got away with it. Maybe I was just lucky - as was my gear! An unregulated psu can almost double the stated voltage with no load, and it would be an unwise move to connect, unless you're in dire straits (or Mark Knofler, who can probably afford to replace gear better than us mere mortals)...

Another important issue is the polarity. With d.c. it's of paramount importance that the pedal gets fed pos. and neg. the right way round. There's often a 50/50, and guessing may mean the pedal doesn't work anyway, and possibly will suffer damage, although most d.c. pedals have a blocking diode.